# Seeking geology fill pattern libraries for QGIS?

Tags: qgis, symbology, geology

I'm making a geological map using QGIS but I don't know how to draw a limestone lithology in QGIS.

To draw other lithologies I combine lines and dots in the best possible way but that is very limited.

Is there a fill pattern library that I can use to do this?

Comment: Can you provide an example of how it should look?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I downloaded the [USGS lithologic patterns](https://blogs.otago.ac.nz/si-geology/resources/illustrationgraphics-resources/usgs-inkscape-pack-instructions-and-download-link/) from the Univeristy of Otago. At the same time, I installed [inkscape](https://inkscape.org/es/descargas/) software to work with these patterns.

Steps to use these patterns in QGIS: 
- Open USGS's patterns file in Inkscape -> Select the pattern you want to use -> File: export as a PNG image. 
I recommend a minimun size of 1125x900 (1500ppp). Don't forget to press 'Export'.

Before converting the PNG image to svg file, crop the borders using any image/photo editor. Otherwise, you will get as a fill pattern a grid of boxes containing the pattern. Now you have a PNG image, go to [imagen.online-convert.com/es/convertir-a-svg](http://imagen.online-convert.com/es/convertir-a-svg) and convert your png image to svg file. 
I don't know why but if you save your file as svg in Inkscape you can't use it in QGIS.

Now with your pattern as a svg file, open QGIS, go to 'Options' -> system -> add a new svg path to the folder where you saved your files. Accept. 
Select a polygon layer and select 'properties' -> style -> select a svg fill. Your folder should appear on the list. Select the pattern you want to use.

About the policy, USGS says that you just have to mention them: 
"Suggested citation U.S. Geological Survey, 2006, FGDC Digital Cartographic Standard for Geologic Map Symbolization (PostScript Implementation): U.S. Geological Survey Techniques and Methods 11-A2 [pubs.usgs.gov/tm/2006/11A02/]."

[image]
[image]

Comment: I followed this and it worked as described. However, is there any way to remove the border around the svg? Using those USGS patterns, and setting as a svg fill in QGIS, you get a grid of of boxes containing the pattern.

Comment: You are right, I forgot to explain this. I've just updated it. I hope you can make it.

Answer (score 5):

I also downloaded the USGS lithologic patterns from the Univeristy of Otago. 
I pulled out the pattern section from the Inkscape template document and used a script to split the xml into individual svg patterns. 
I ran them through "SVG Cleaner" and opened in Inkscape to make sure the rotations and spacings were correct, and saved as plain svg. I then made a batch with the stroke color (or fill where required) as a parameter so they can be attributed to any color in QGIS.
you can find all the patterns here:

https://github.com/cecgeology/USGS-FGDC

There is also a QGIS workspace that shows all the patterns (and some blanks for future expansion)

Answer (score 4):

Look into the using the [SVG fill](https://docs.qgis.org/2.8/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/style_library.html#polygon-symbols) symbol layer type in QGIS, to use a repeating SVG pattern of your choice.

The USGS lithologic patterns have already been converted to SVG and are available from the University of Otago [here](https://blogs.otago.ac.nz/si-geology/resources/illustrationgraphics-resources/usgs-inkscape-pack-instructions-and-download-link/) with a description on how to edit them. A similar starting point to making patterns would be to look at the [BGS](http://nora.nerc.ac.uk/3221/1/RR01001.pdf) area ornaments.

I'm not sure what the policy is on reuse of these sources.